# Call getServerSideProps with parameters from FE in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

I want to achieve the following

- FE input a `string` and press `translate` button
- pass the value of that string to the `getServerSideProps` in the `Home` (parent) component
- use that value to call `fetchDBData()` in order to use the `findOne` method in MongoDB
- and I want to present the fetched Data back to FE (Child component)

I could call `getchAllDBData()` in `getServerSideProps` and filter the result in the frontend. But

**Question**:
How to pass the value from FE input to inside of getServerSideProps directly? [without through dynamic router]

Data flow

- press translate button in the child component,
- pass the input value here(e.g. 11) to getServerSideProps in the parentComponent,
- getServerSideProps,`await fetchDBData(`11`)`, and pass it to the `props` in return
- getServerSideProps return `props` to parentComponent
- parentComponent pass `props` value to childComponent
- childComponent renders the received `props` data

[FE layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5igG.png)

## Child component

```
function StartingPageContent({ props, getChild }: any) {
  // Show Link to Login page if NOT auth
  const searchResult = props.data;

  const inputRef = useRef() as any;

  const translate = () => {
        getChild(inputRef.current.value)
 };

return (
    <section>
      <div className="relative inset-0 flex justify-center items-center">
         
        {/* Search Input */}
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <div className="flex flex-row">
            <div className="flex  mx-8">
              <Input
                placeholder="Input name"
                size="lg"
                type="text"
                id="name"
                ref={inputRef}
              />
              <input />
            </div>

            {/* Search Button*/}
            <div className="flex  mx-8">
              <Button colorScheme="teal" size="lg" onClick={translate}>
                Translate
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Search Result */}

          <Container className="mt-8" maxW="2xl" bg="gray.100" centerContent>
            <span>From DB</span>
            <Box padding="4" margin="4" bg="gray.300" color="black" maxW="md">
              <span>{searchResult.translation}</span>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

}
```

## Parent Component under `pages` folder

Here is getServerSideProps in index.tsx

```
export default function Home(props: any) {
  const [childData, setChildData] = useState('')
  function getChild(data: any) {
     setChildData(childData)
  }
  return (
    <main
      className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 `}
    >
      <StartingPageContent props={props} getChild={getChild} />
    </main>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const result = await fetchDBData(PARAM); <==== How to obtain the value of `childData` from Home component
  const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));

  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
```

## Here is the connection to MongoDB

```
export async function fetchDBData(name: string): Promise<any | undefined> {
  const client = await connectToUserDatabase();
  const userCollection = client.db().collection("target");

  const result = await userCollection.findOne({
    name: name,
  });

  if (!!result) {
    return result;
  }
  return undefined;
}

// Here is the method if I want to filter in the FE
export async function fetchAllDBData(): Promise<any | undefined> {
  const client = await connectToUserDatabase();
  const userCollection = client.db().collection("target");

  const result = await userCollection.find({}).toArray();

  if (!!result) {
    return result;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: You can do a client-side navigation to the page with a query param with the string. `getServerSideProps` will fire, and you can retrieve the query from the `context` object. See [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) for reference on the context parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is by passing your input value to the url so that the getServerSideProps fire inside that you can get the url parameters
Try the following

### Parent Page

```
import StartingPageContent from '@components/test';

export default function Home(props: any) {
    return (
        <main className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 `}>
            <StartingPageContent props={props} />
        </main>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // you will get the url params in here (context.query.q) if available
    const result = await fetchDBData(context.query.q ?? '');
    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));

    if (!data) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false,
            },
        };
    }

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
    };
}
```

### Child Component

```
function StartingPageContent({ props }: any) {
  const { push } = useRouter();
    const searchResult = props.data;

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const translate = () => {
        // change router with useRouter from next/router
        push(`/<YOUR_PAGE_NAME>?q=${input}`);
    };

return (
    <section>
      <div className="relative inset-0 flex justify-center items-center">
         
        {/* Search Input */}
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <div className="flex flex-row">
            <div className="flex  mx-8">
               <Input placeholder="Input name" type="text" id="name" onChange={e => setInput(() => e.target.value)} />
            </div>

            {/* Search Button*/}
            <div className="flex  mx-8">
              <Button colorScheme="teal" size="lg" onClick={translate}>
                Translate
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Search Result */}

          <Container className="mt-8" maxW="2xl" bg="gray.100" centerContent>
            <span>From DB</span>
            <Box padding="4" margin="4" bg="gray.300" color="black" maxW="md">
              <span>{searchResult.translation}</span>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

}
```